# unable to create primary key on phpmyadmin sql

Tags: sql

this is my code

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
 id integer NOT NULL,
name varchar(12),
orderno int,
city varchar(12), 
price int
PRIMARY KEY ('id')
```

);

please check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJWgm.png) for error

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Better than posting an image link, is to post the error message (the text below "MySQL said:") as text.

Comment: Just do what the error message said: 
*You have an error in your SQL; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'id') )` at line 7*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(12),
orderno int,
city varchar(12), 
price int
);
```

Answer (score 0):

While Creating Table you can Declare the primary key Attribute with the type of the attribute. like.
CREATE TABLE orders(
 id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name varchar(12),
orderno int,
city varchar(12), 
price int);

Comment: You are Welcome.